# Plotting the cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, plot, cell-array

I have two 1-D cell arrays with numbers inside, how can I plot this?

```
X = {'1' '2' '35' }
Y = {'23' '30' '90' }
```

I am trying to `plot` the two cell arrays using plot command:

```
plot (X,Y);
```

And I received the following the error:

```
Not enough input arguments.
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to first convert your cell arrays of strings to an array of numbers. You can do this using [`str2double`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/str2double.html)

```
X = {'1' '2' '35' }
Y = {'23' '30' '90' }

plot(str2double(X), str2double(Y))
```

[image]